# Last Node on Kendo TreeView

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I need to handle some special logic on the last node in the TreeView as I iterate through every node in the tree. Is there an easy way to tell if it's the last node?

Answer (score 0):

you can find the last node of kendo treeview by adding the dataBound event of kendo treeview where you can check index of element and compare it with total items of datasource.

hope this will help you